# How to install lxml on Windows

Tags: python, windows, python-3.x, pip, lxml

I'm trying to install `lmxl` on my Windows 8.1 laptop with Python 3.4 and failing miserably.

First off, I tried the simple and obvious solution: `pip install lxml`. However, this didn't work. Here's what it said:

```
Downloading/unpacking lxml
  Running setup.py (path:C:\Users\CARTE_~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip_build_carte_000\lxml\setup.py) egg_info for package lxml
    Building lxml version 3.4.2.
    Building without Cython.
    ERROR: b"'xslt-config' is not recognized as an internal or external command,\r\noperable program or batch file.\r\n"
    ** make sure the development packages of libxml2 and libxslt are installed **

    Using build configuration of libxslt
    C:\Python34\lib\distutils\dist.py:260: UserWarning: Unknown distribution option: 'bugtrack_url'
      warnings.warn(msg)

    warning: no previously-included files found matching '*.py'
Installing collected packages: lxml
  Running setup.py install for lxml
    Building lxml version 3.4.2.
    Building without Cython.
    ERROR: b"'xslt-config' is not recognized as an internal or external command,\r\noperable program or batch file.\r\n"
    ** make sure the development packages of libxml2 and libxslt are installed **

    Using build configuration of libxslt
    building 'lxml.etree' extension
    C:\Python34\lib\distutils\dist.py:260: UserWarning: Unknown distribution option: 'bugtrack_url'
      warnings.warn(msg)
    error: Unable to find vcvarsall.bat
    Complete output from command C:\Python34\python.exe -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='C:\\Users\\CARTE_~1\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip_build_carte_000\\lxml\\setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record C:\Users\CARTE_~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-l8vvrv9g-record\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile:
    Building lxml version 3.4.2.

Building without Cython.

ERROR: b"'xslt-config' is not recognized as an internal or external command,\r\noperable program or batch file.\r\n"

** make sure the development packages of libxml2 and libxslt are installed **



Using build configuration of libxslt

running install

running build

running build_py

creating build

creating build\lib.win32-3.4

creating build\lib.win32-3.4\lxml

copying src\lxml\builder.py -> build\lib.win32-3.4\lxml

copying src\lxml\cssselect.py -> build\lib.win32-3.4\lxml

copying src\lxml\doctestcompare.py -> build\lib.win32-3.4\lxml

copying src\lxml\ElementInclude.py -> build\lib.win32-3.4\lxml

copying src\lxml\pyclasslookup.py -> build\lib.win32-3.4\lxml

copying src\lxml\sax.py -> build\lib.win32-3.4\lxml

copying src\lxml\usedoctest.py -> build\lib.win32-3.4\lxml

copying src\lxml\_elementpath.py -> build\lib.win32-3.4\lxml

copying src\lxml\__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-3.4\lxml

creating build\lib.win32-3.4\lxml\includes

copying src\lxml\includes\__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-3.4\lxml\includes

creating build\lib.win32-3.4\lxml\html

copying src\lxml\html\builder.py -> build\lib.win32-3.4\lxml\html

copying src\lxml\html\clean.py -> build\lib.win32-3.4\lxml\html

copying src\lxml\html\defs.py -> build\lib.win32-3.4\lxml\html

copying src\lxml\html\diff.py -> build\lib.win32-3.4\lxml\html

copying src\lxml\html\ElementSoup.py -> build\lib.win32-3.4\lxml\html

copying src\lxml\html\formfill.py -> build\lib.win32-3.4\lxml\html

copying src\lxml\html\html5parser.py -> build\lib.win32-3.4\lxml\html

copying src\lxml\html\soupparser.py -> build\lib.win32-3.4\lxml\html

copying src\lxml\html\usedoctest.py -> build\lib.win32-3.4\lxml\html

copying src\lxml\html\_diffcommand.py -> build\lib.win32-3.4\lxml\html

copying src\lxml\html\_html5builder.py -> build\lib.win32-3.4\lxml\html

copying src\lxml\html\_setmixin.py -> build\lib.win32-3.4\lxml\html

copying src\lxml\html\__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-3.4\lxml\html

creating build\lib.win32-3.4\lxml\isoschematron

copying src\lxml\isoschematron\__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-3.4\lxml\isoschematron

copying src\lxml\lxml.etree.h -> build\lib.win32-3.4\lxml

copying src\lxml\lxml.etree_api.h -> build\lib.win32-3.4\lxml

copying src\lxml\includes\c14n.pxd -> build\lib.win32-3.4\lxml\includes

copying src\lxml\includes\config.pxd -> build\lib.win32-3.4\lxml\includes

copying src\lxml\includes\dtdvalid.pxd -> build\lib.win32-3.4\lxml\includes

copying src\lxml\includes\etreepublic.pxd -> build\lib.win32-3.4\lxml\includes

copying src\lxml\includes\htmlparser.pxd -> build\lib.win32-3.4\lxml\includes

copying src\lxml\includes\relaxng.pxd -> build\lib.win32-3.4\lxml\includes

copying src\lxml\includes\schematron.pxd -> build\lib.win32-3.4\lxml\includes

copying src\lxml\includes\tree.pxd -> build\lib.win32-3.4\lxml\includes

copying src\lxml\includes\uri.pxd -> build\lib.win32-3.4\lxml\includes

copying src\lxml\includes\xinclude.pxd -> build\lib.win32-3.4\lxml\includes

copying src\lxml\includes\xmlerror.pxd -> build\lib.win32-3.4\lxml\includes

copying src\lxml\includes\xmlparser.pxd -> build\lib.win32-3.4\lxml\includes

copying src\lxml\includes\xmlschema.pxd -> build\lib.win32-3.4\lxml\includes

copying src\lxml\includes\xpath.pxd -> build\lib.win32-3.4\lxml\includes

copying src\lxml\includes\xslt.pxd -> build\lib.win32-3.4\lxml\includes

copying src\lxml\includes\etree_defs.h -> build\lib.win32-3.4\lxml\includes

copying src\lxml\includes\lxml-version.h -> build\lib.win32-3.4\lxml\includes

creating build\lib.win32-3.4\lxml\isoschematron\resources

creating build\lib.win32-3.4\lxml\isoschematron\resources\rng

copying src\lxml\isoschematron\resources\rng\iso-schematron.rng -> build\lib.win32-3.4\lxml\isoschematron\resources\rng

creating build\lib.win32-3.4\lxml\isoschematron\resources\xsl

copying src\lxml\isoschematron\resources\xsl\RNG2Schtrn.xsl -> build\lib.win32-3.4\lxml\isoschematron\resources\xsl

copying src\lxml\isoschematron\resources\xsl\XSD2Schtrn.xsl -> build\lib.win32-3.4\lxml\isoschematron\resources\xsl

creating build\lib.win32-3.4\lxml\isoschematron\resources\xsl\iso-schematron-xslt1

copying src\lxml\isoschematron\resources\xsl\iso-schematron-xslt1\iso_abstract_expand.xsl -> build\lib.win32-3.4\lxml\isoschematron\resources\xsl\iso-schematron-xslt1

copying src\lxml\isoschematron\resources\xsl\iso-schematron-xslt1\iso_dsdl_include.xsl -> build\lib.win32-3.4\lxml\isoschematron\resources\xsl\iso-schematron-xslt1

copying src\lxml\isoschematron\resources\xsl\iso-schematron-xslt1\iso_schematron_message.xsl -> build\lib.win32-3.4\lxml\isoschematron\resources\xsl\iso-schematron-xslt1

copying src\lxml\isoschematron\resources\xsl\iso-schematron-xslt1\iso_schematron_skeleton_for_xslt1.xsl -> build\lib.win32-3.4\lxml\isoschematron\resources\xsl\iso-schematron-xslt1

copying src\lxml\isoschematron\resources\xsl\iso-schematron-xslt1\iso_svrl_for_xslt1.xsl -> build\lib.win32-3.4\lxml\isoschematron\resources\xsl\iso-schematron-xslt1

copying src\lxml\isoschematron\resources\xsl\iso-schematron-xslt1\readme.txt -> build\lib.win32-3.4\lxml\isoschematron\resources\xsl\iso-schematron-xslt1

running build_ext

building 'lxml.etree' extension

C:\Python34\lib\distutils\dist.py:260: UserWarning: Unknown distribution option: 'bugtrack_url'

  warnings.warn(msg)

error: Unable to find vcvarsall.bat

----------------------------------------
Cleaning up...
Command C:\Python34\python.exe -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='C:\\Users\\CARTE_~1\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip_build_carte_000\\lxml\\setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record C:\Users\CARTE_~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-l8vvrv9g-record\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\CARTE_~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip_build_carte_000\lxml
Storing debug log for failure in C:\Users\carte_000\pip\pip.log
```

So then I looked on this great and helpful thing called *The Internet* and a lot of people have the same error of needing `libxml2` and `libxlst`. They recommend a guy called Christoph Gohlke's page where he provides some sort of binary thingy for a bunch of packages. You can find it [here](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/) ([quicklink to the lxml part](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#lxml)).

So after I gave up on trying to find libxml2 and libxslt for pip, I decided to go there, and found *an absolute ton* of downloads. I know I need a 64-bit one, but I have no idea which "`cp`" I need.

So an answer either giving me a solution on the `pip` method or the Gohlke index method would be great.

Comment: Pretty sure `cp` means C-Python in this context, and you should match the values after it with the python version you are wanting to support.  So `cp33` would be for Python 3.3 .

Comment: Hi lxml can be installed and upldated via pip easily 123, so please change the accepted answer to let others know there is no need to manually download and install whl.

Comment: Check George Answer guys

Answer (score 12, accepted):

First, following the comments, I downloaded the `lxml-3.4.2-cp34-none-win_amd64.whl` file and tried to open it with a `pip install`, but it just told me it wasn't a valid wheel file on my system or something.

Then, I downloaded the `win_32` file and it worked! Maybe it's because I have an Intel processor and AMD64 is, unsurprisingly, only for AMD processors.

Comment: "In short, in today technology, AMD64 is now referring to the 64-bit architecture and is not tied with the AMD CPU." from [here](https://www.maketecheasier.com/can-i-install-amd64-ubuntu-on-my-intel-64-bit-machine/)

Answer (score 36):

Or you can also go to [Christoph's Gohlke's Python page](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/%7Egohlke/pythonlibs/#lxml) and then download the right lxml file. (Generally since I use python 3.4 and I have a windows, I download the lxml-3.4.4-cp34-none-win32.whl)

Go to the folder it is in. Click in the background (so nothing is selected), then leftshift + rightclick at the same time and click on open command window. Then type
C:/Python34/Scripts/pip install "NAME OF THE FILE YOU JUST DOWNLOADED.whl"

In this case it would be C:/Python34/Scripts/pip install "lxml-3.4.4-cp34-none-win32.whl"

Now hit enter. This worked well for me, and after you type the quote you can also press tab and it should fill the right one for you.

Comment: Thanks! On my Win 7 64bit with python 3.4 I used: `C:\Python34>pip install lxml-3.4.4-cp34-none-win_amd64.whl`

Comment: It worked for me on my Win 10 64-bit python 3.7.3. I used 
   C:\Users\Admin\Downloads>pip install lxml-4.3.3-cp37-cp37m-win_amd64.whl 
   as my .whl file was present in Downloads.

Comment: Now whenever you want to update lxml you have to redo it manually? I miss my manjaro:(

Comment: The link is you provided is dead.

Answer (score 7):

Looks like today in 2018, `lxml` can be installed from PyPI:

```
C:\Users\Administrator>"c:\Program Files\Python37\python.exe" -m pip install -U pip wheel setuptools
Collecting pip
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/c2/d7/90f34cb0d83a6c5631cf71dfe64cc1054598c843a92b400e55675cc2ac37/pip-18.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (1.3MB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 1.3MB 3.3MB/s
Collecting wheel
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/5a/9b/6aebe9e2636d35d1a93772fa644c828303e1d5d124e8a88f156f42ac4b87/wheel-0.32.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting setuptools
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/96/06/c8ee69628191285ddddffb277bd5abdf769166e7a14b867c2a172f0175b1/setuptools-40.4.3-py2.py3-none-any.whl (569kB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 573kB 2.9MB/s
Installing collected packages: pip, wheel, setuptools
  Found existing installation: pip 10.0.1
    Uninstalling pip-10.0.1:
      Successfully uninstalled pip-10.0.1
  The script wheel.exe is installed in 'c:\Program Files\Python37\Scripts' which is not on PATH.
  Consider adding this directory to PATH or, if you prefer to suppress this warning, use --no-warn-script-location.
  Found existing installation: setuptools 39.0.1
    Uninstalling setuptools-39.0.1:
      Successfully uninstalled setuptools-39.0.1
Successfully installed pip-18.1 setuptools-40.4.3 wheel-0.32.2

C:\Users\Administrator>pip install lxml
Collecting lxml
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/d7/9d/1aa28aa9d293a816baec6c37328d6465b722b2ff3f4d1e93ed56e87813ee/lxml-4.2.5-cp37-cp37m-win_amd64.whl (3.6MB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 3.6MB 1.6MB/s
Installing collected packages: lxml
Successfully installed lxml-4.2.5

C:\Users\Administrator>python
Python 3.7.1 (v3.7.1:260ec2c36a, Oct 20 2018, 14:57:15) [MSC v.1915 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from io import BytesIO
>>> some_file_or_file_like_object = BytesIO(b"<root>data</root>")
>>> from lxml import etree
>>> tree = etree.parse(some_file_or_file_like_object)
>>> etree.tostring(tree)
b'<root>data</root>'
```

Comment: It's 2020  and thanks to George i could install lxml just using pip on windows. So for now this should be the accepted answer

Answer (score 3):

**These instructions are for Windows7 or Windows8 with Python3.4**.

**However**, they should work for various versions as the releases of python and other respective prerequisites change/evolve:

1. Install ***Python3.4***:

   1. Download the last release of Python3.4 from the downloads page [HERE](https://www.python.org/downloads/release/python-34/)

      - Direct link for Win32 MSI installer -> [HERE](http://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.4/python-3.4.msi)
   2. Simply run the MSI to install python.  It will register itself in the registry, and appear in Add/REmove Programs.
   3. **NOTE:** my instructions that follow assume that you choose to install python to the default path of `C:\python34\` when asked during the Python Installation Wizard
2. Add the `C:\python33\` and `C:\python34\scripts` folders to the system path by adding those directories to the `PATH` environment variable from the **Control Panel > System > Advanced System Settings link (Advanced Tab) > Environmental Variables (Button)**.
3. Install ***OpenSSL***:

   1. Download **Win32 OpenSSL page** from [HERE](http://slproweb.com/products/Win32OpenSSL.html) for your version of Windows and PC architecture
   2. Download **Visual C++ 2008 redistributables** for your version of Windows and PC architecture
   3. Download **OpenSSL** for your version of Windows and architecture (the regular version, not the light one)
   4. Add the `c:\openssl-win32\bin` (or similar) directory to your `PATH`, the same way you added `C:\python34` and `C:\python34\scripts` above.
4. Install ***Setuptools*** (`get-pip.py` should install Setuptools for you), but, just in case...

   1. Download `ez_setup.py` [HERE](https://bitbucket.org/pypa/setuptools/raw/bootstrap/ez_setup.py) and save it in `C:\python34\scripts`
   2. Run **`C:\python34\scripts> python ez_setup.py`**
5. Install ***PIP***

   1. Download `get-pip.py` from [HERE](https://raw.github.com/pypa/pip/master/contrib/get-pip.py) and save it in `C:\python34\scripts`
   2. Run **`C:\python34\scripts> python get-pip.py`**
6. Install ***LXML***

   1. Download `LXML 3.4.4` from [HERE](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/lxml/3.4.4) for your version of Windows and PC architecture
   2. Run the EXE file

Comment: .exe files are no longer available for lxml on pypi.org.

Answer (score 3):

I had this issue with a requirements file that listed lxml==4.2.1. However, I was able to fix the problem by updating this to lxml==4.2.5.

Comment: this saved my day, Do anyone happen to know why lxml==4.2.5 worked but not the 4.2.3

Comment: [This](https://github.com/lxml/lxml/pull/259) fix was added to version 4.2.4. Perhaps that might be the reason. 

You can see the release notes [here](https://lxml.de/4.4/changes-4.4.0.html#id17)

Answer (score 2):

I also meet this problem recently. pip can't not work on .whl file. Instead of fixing this, i install it through .exe file. you can download it from [here](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/lxml/3.8.0).Please choose the right version of your python. Hope this can help you.

Comment: The problem is that (a year later, admittedly) PyPi only has wheel files, no .exe any longer :-(

Answer (score 1):

From the distributer's website, the correct command is:

```
pip install lxml==3.4.4
```

Of course, update version number to match the latest version.

Reference: https://pypi.org/project/lxml/3.4.4/

Answer (score 0):

Go to this page - [https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#lxml](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/%7Egohlke/pythonlibs/#lxml)

Download the libxml which is compatible with you machine.
For example, in my case, I have 64-bit intel processor with python 3.10 installed.
so , I have downloaded  lxml‑4.6.3‑cp310‑cp310‑win_amd64.whl .

then run -

```
pip install "download_path/lxml-4.6.3-cp310-cp310-win_amd64.whl"
```

Comment: Use pipwin for installing from this website

Comment: When trying to to that, I get  *ERROR: lxml-4.5.2-cp39-cp39-win_amd64.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform.*.