# Using lxml for Python - Windows 7 64-bit

Tags: python, windows, lxml

When I try to install lxml, I get the following. I've tried downloading C++ redists and a whole bunch of other things I've found, but nothing works.

I've tried everything from the following link:

[How to install lxml on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29440482/how-to-install-lxml-on-windows)

I've got python version 3.5.1. I

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 6.1.7601]
Copyright (c) 2009 Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

C:\Users\daniel.bak>pip install setuptools
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): setuptools in c:\users\daniel.bak\appdata\local\programs\python\python35-32\lib\site-packages

C:\Users\daniel.bak>pip install lxml
Collecting lxml
  Using cached lxml-3.6.0.tar.gz
Installing collected packages: lxml
  Running setup.py install for lxml ... error
    Complete output from command c:\users\daniel.bak\appdata\local\programs\python\python35-32\python.exe -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='C:\\Users\\daniel.bak\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-build-_d7bp49n\\lxml\\setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replac
e('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record C:\Users\daniel.bak\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-4wmqb1li-record\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile:
    Building lxml version 3.6.0.
    Building without Cython.
    ERROR: b"'xslt-config' is not recognized as an internal or external command,\r\noperable program or batch file.\r\n"
    ** make sure the development packages of libxml2 and libxslt are installed **

    Using build configuration of libxslt
    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    creating build
    creating build\lib.win32-3.5
    creating build\lib.win32-3.5\lxml
    copying src\lxml\builder.py -> build\lib.win32-3.5\lxml
    copying src\lxml\cssselect.py -> build\lib.win32-3.5\lxml
    copying src\lxml\doctestcompare.py -> build\lib.win32-3.5\lxml
    copying src\lxml\ElementInclude.py -> build\lib.win32-3.5\lxml
    copying src\lxml\pyclasslookup.py -> build\lib.win32-3.5\lxml
    copying src\lxml\sax.py -> build\lib.win32-3.5\lxml
    copying src\lxml\usedoctest.py -> build\lib.win32-3.5\lxml
    copying src\lxml\_elementpath.py -> build\lib.win32-3.5\lxml
    copying src\lxml\__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-3.5\lxml
    creating build\lib.win32-3.5\lxml\includes
    copying src\lxml\includes\__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-3.5\lxml\includes
    creating build\lib.win32-3.5\lxml\html
    copying src\lxml\html\builder.py -> build\lib.win32-3.5\lxml\html
    copying src\lxml\html\clean.py -> build\lib.win32-3.5\lxml\html
    copying src\lxml\html\defs.py -> build\lib.win32-3.5\lxml\html
    copying src\lxml\html\diff.py -> build\lib.win32-3.5\lxml\html
    copying src\lxml\html\ElementSoup.py -> build\lib.win32-3.5\lxml\html
    copying src\lxml\html\formfill.py -> build\lib.win32-3.5\lxml\html
    copying src\lxml\html\html5parser.py -> build\lib.win32-3.5\lxml\html
    copying src\lxml\html\soupparser.py -> build\lib.win32-3.5\lxml\html
    copying src\lxml\html\usedoctest.py -> build\lib.win32-3.5\lxml\html
    copying src\lxml\html\_diffcommand.py -> build\lib.win32-3.5\lxml\html
    copying src\lxml\html\_html5builder.py -> build\lib.win32-3.5\lxml\html
    copying src\lxml\html\_setmixin.py -> build\lib.win32-3.5\lxml\html
    copying src\lxml\html\__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-3.5\lxml\html
    creating build\lib.win32-3.5\lxml\isoschematron
    copying src\lxml\isoschematron\__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-3.5\lxml\isoschematron
    copying src\lxml\lxml.etree.h -> build\lib.win32-3.5\lxml
    copying src\lxml\lxml.etree_api.h -> build\lib.win32-3.5\lxml
    copying src\lxml\includes\c14n.pxd -> build\lib.win32-3.5\lxml\includes
    copying src\lxml\includes\config.pxd -> build\lib.win32-3.5\lxml\includes
    copying src\lxml\includes\dtdvalid.pxd -> build\lib.win32-3.5\lxml\includes
    copying src\lxml\includes\etreepublic.pxd -> build\lib.win32-3.5\lxml\includes
    copying src\lxml\includes\htmlparser.pxd -> build\lib.win32-3.5\lxml\includes
    copying src\lxml\includes\relaxng.pxd -> build\lib.win32-3.5\lxml\includes
    copying src\lxml\includes\schematron.pxd -> build\lib.win32-3.5\lxml\includes
    copying src\lxml\includes\tree.pxd -> build\lib.win32-3.5\lxml\includes
    copying src\lxml\includes\uri.pxd -> build\lib.win32-3.5\lxml\includes
    copying src\lxml\includes\xinclude.pxd -> build\lib.win32-3.5\lxml\includes
    copying src\lxml\includes\xmlerror.pxd -> build\lib.win32-3.5\lxml\includes
    copying src\lxml\includes\xmlparser.pxd -> build\lib.win32-3.5\lxml\includes
    copying src\lxml\includes\xmlschema.pxd -> build\lib.win32-3.5\lxml\includes
    copying src\lxml\includes\xpath.pxd -> build\lib.win32-3.5\lxml\includes
    copying src\lxml\includes\xslt.pxd -> build\lib.win32-3.5\lxml\includes
    copying src\lxml\includes\etree_defs.h -> build\lib.win32-3.5\lxml\includes
    copying src\lxml\includes\lxml-version.h -> build\lib.win32-3.5\lxml\includes
    creating build\lib.win32-3.5\lxml\isoschematron\resources
    creating build\lib.win32-3.5\lxml\isoschematron\resources\rng
    copying src\lxml\isoschematron\resources\rng\iso-schematron.rng -> build\lib.win32-3.5\lxml\isoschematron\resources\rng
    creating build\lib.win32-3.5\lxml\isoschematron\resources\xsl
    copying src\lxml\isoschematron\resources\xsl\RNG2Schtrn.xsl -> build\lib.win32-3.5\lxml\isoschematron\resources\xsl
    copying src\lxml\isoschematron\resources\xsl\XSD2Schtrn.xsl -> build\lib.win32-3.5\lxml\isoschematron\resources\xsl
    creating build\lib.win32-3.5\lxml\isoschematron\resources\xsl\iso-schematron-xslt1
    copying src\lxml\isoschematron\resources\xsl\iso-schematron-xslt1\iso_abstract_expand.xsl -> build\lib.win32-3.5\lxml\isoschematron\resources\xsl\iso-schematron-xslt1
    copying src\lxml\isoschematron\resources\xsl\iso-schematron-xslt1\iso_dsdl_include.xsl -> build\lib.win32-3.5\lxml\isoschematron\resources\xsl\iso-schematron-xslt1
    copying src\lxml\isoschematron\resources\xsl\iso-schematron-xslt1\iso_schematron_message.xsl -> build\lib.win32-3.5\lxml\isoschematron\resources\xsl\iso-schematron-xslt1
    copying src\lxml\isoschematron\resources\xsl\iso-schematron-xslt1\iso_schematron_skeleton_for_xslt1.xsl -> build\lib.win32-3.5\lxml\isoschematron\resources\xsl\iso-schematron-xslt1
    copying src\lxml\isoschematron\resources\xsl\iso-schematron-xslt1\iso_svrl_for_xslt1.xsl -> build\lib.win32-3.5\lxml\isoschematron\resources\xsl\iso-schematron-xslt1
    copying src\lxml\isoschematron\resources\xsl\iso-schematron-xslt1\readme.txt -> build\lib.win32-3.5\lxml\isoschematron\resources\xsl\iso-schematron-xslt1
    running build_ext
    building 'lxml.etree' extension
    error: Unable to find vcvarsall.bat

    ----------------------------------------
Command "c:\users\daniel.bak\appdata\local\programs\python\python35-32\python.exe -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='C:\\Users\\daniel.bak\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-build-_d7bp49n\\lxml\\setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file_
_, 'exec'))" install --record C:\Users\daniel.bak\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-4wmqb1li-record\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\daniel.bak\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-_d7bp49n\lxml\
```

Installing the precompiled binaries gives me:

```
C:\Users\daniel.bak>pip install "C:\Users\daniel.bak\Downloads\lxml-3.6.0-cp35-cp35m-win_amd64.whl"
lxml-3.6.0-cp35-cp35m-win_amd64.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform.
```

Comment: I do not always use Python, but when I do use Python, I prefer the Anaconda distribution. You typically install with `conda install <packagename>` unless the package is already within the distro. Also take a look at `VirtualEnv`  https://pypi.python.org/pypi/virtualenv on how to easily manage multiple installations w/o breaking your existing ones.

Comment: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/pythonengineering/2016/04/11/unable-to-find-vcvarsall-bat/

Comment: Are you certain that you have a 64bit python installation?  What is the full first line of output when you start python from the command prompt with `python` (on mine for example it reads: `Python 3.5.0 (v3.5.0:374f501f4567, Sep 13 2015, 02:27:37) [MSC v.1900 64bit (AMD64)] on win32 `)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can download precompiled binaries and install them with `pip install`

Here is the [download link](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#lxml). `cp27`, `cp34`, `cp35` indicate Python versions and `win32` and `win_amd64` 32 and 64 bit packages.

Comment: I can't get this to work. 

C:\Users\daniel.bak>pip install "C:\Users\daniel.bak\Downloads\lxml-3.6.0-cp35-cp35m-win_amd64.whl"
lxml-3.6.0-cp35-cp35m-win_amd64.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform.

Comment: python -m pip install "C:\Users\daniel.bak\Downloads\lxml-3.6.0-cp35-cp35m-win_amd64.whl" lxml-3.6.0-cp35-cp35m-win_amd64.whl

Comment: Use the command above and it should work if python 3.5 is on your PATH

Answer (score -1):

I was having trouble installing lxml on my system as well along with urllib. I do not remember why but lxml was not available for python 3.5, urllib itself is not available but instead it is available as urllib.requests and another package that I do not remember. For me the best solution was to install anaconda instead. Anaconda has just so many libraries and it works greatly in place of python. It has the whole url library and a comprehension of several other libraries.