# lxml error in python3.4 installation

Tags: python, lxml, python-3.4, libxml2, libxslt

I'm trying to run the following command in command prompt -

```
pip install -r requirements.txt
```

But it shows so many errors and I have no idea how to resolve them as I'm not familiar with python.

The errors are:
1.

```
Collecting lxml==3.5.0 (from -r requirements.txt (line 1))
  Using cached lxml-3.5.0.tar.gz
Collecting pyquery==1.2.10 (from -r requirements.txt (line 2))
Collecting cssselect>0.7.9 (from pyquery==1.2.10->-r requirements.txt (line 2))




     Using cached cssselect-1.0.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl
        Building wheels for collected packages: lxml
          Running setup.py bdist_wheel for lxml ... error
          Complete output from command c:\python34\python.exe -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='C:\\Users\\Mohana\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-build-9bz1xoev\\lxml\\setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" bdist_wheel -d C:\Users\Mohana\AppData\Local\Temp\tmp425xg1fhpip-wheel- --python-tag cp34:
          Building lxml version 3.5.0.
          Building without Cython.
          ERROR: b"'xslt-config' is not recognized as an internal or external command,\r\noperable program or batch file.\r\n"
          ** make sure the development packages of libxml2 and libxslt are installed **

2. 

    src\lxml\includes\etree_defs.h(14) : fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'libxml/xmlversion.h': No such file or directory
      Compile failed: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\\VC\\Bin\\cl.exe' failed with exit status 2
      creating Users
      creating Users\Mohana
      creating Users\Mohana\AppData
      creating Users\Mohana\AppData\Local
      creating Users\Mohana\AppData\Local\Temp
      C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\Bin\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /MD /W3 /GS- /DNDEBUG -I/usr/include/libxml2 /TcC:\Users\Mohana\AppData\Local\Temp\xmlXPathInitocb5oi7w.c /FoUsers\Mohana\AppData\Local\Temp\xmlXPathInitocb5oi7w.obj
      xmlXPathInitocb5oi7w.c
      C:\Users\Mohana\AppData\Local\Temp\xmlXPathInitocb5oi7w.c(1) : fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'libxml/xpath.h': No such file or directory
      *********************************************************************************
      Could not find function xmlCheckVersion in library libxml2. Is libxml2 installed?
      *********************************************************************************
      error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\\VC\\Bin\\cl.exe' failed with exit status 2
```

3.

```
Failed building wheel for lxml
  Running setup.py clean for lxml
Failed to build lxml
Installing collected packages: lxml, cssselect, pyquery
  Found existing installation: lxml 4.0.0
    Uninstalling lxml-4.0.0:
      Successfully uninstalled lxml-4.0.0
  Running setup.py install for lxml ... error
    Complete output from command c:\python34\python.exe -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='C:\\Users\\Mohana\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-build-9bz1xoev\\lxml\\setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record C:\Users\Mohana\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-rjvm3d2l-record\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile:
    Building lxml version 3.5.0.
    Building without Cython.
    ERROR: b"'xslt-config' is not recognized as an internal or external command,\r\noperable program or batch file.\r\n"
    ** make sure the development packages of libxml2 and libxslt are installed **


4. 

    src\lxml\includes\etree_defs.h(14) : fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'libxml/xmlversion.h': No such file or directory
        Compile failed: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\\VC\\Bin\\cl.exe' failed with exit status 2
        C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\Bin\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /MD /W3 /GS- /DNDEBUG -I/usr/include/libxml2 /TcC:\Users\Mohana\AppData\Local\Temp\xmlXPathInity8a5suic.c /FoUsers\Mohana\AppData\Local\Temp\xmlXPathInity8a5suic.obj
        xmlXPathInity8a5suic.c
        C:\Users\Mohana\AppData\Local\Temp\xmlXPathInity8a5suic.c(1) : fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'libxml/xpath.h': No such file or directory
        *********************************************************************************
        Could not find function xmlCheckVersion in library libxml2. Is libxml2 installed?
        *********************************************************************************
        error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\\VC\\Bin\\cl.exe' failed with exit status 2
```

Please help me solve these issues, I need it for a project and I really need to get it done. I am on Windows 10 (Intel processors) and Python3.4.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to install lxml on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29440482/how-to-install-lxml-on-windows)

Answer (score 1):

As @SaeX says in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33785756), you can find the precompiled
 WHL of lxml with the required modules and dependencies [here](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#lxml).

For Python 3.4 and win10 your file should be `lxml‑4.1.0‑cp34‑cp34m‑win_amd64.whl`. Then you can install it by using pip:

`pip install lxml‑4.1.0‑cp34‑cp34m‑win_amd64.whl`

Answer (score 0):

For python 3.4 or above,

In command Prompt,
type **pip3 install lxml** in case if you want to download and install from network automatically
otheriwse, download .whl file of lxml from the below

For 32 bit : [Download Here](https://pypi.python.org/packages/15/64/ddf905b001ef56bdd50dd372861b1c892719acd8378169218b7a6ce4c93b/lxml-4.1.1-cp34-cp34m-win32.whl#md5=1241702a6d634eb6d62a002d0da4e905)

For 64 bit : [Download Here](https://pypi.python.org/packages/c7/fe/d93ad810761f570d49f16aacea8647ae70295821028ca7e85fdc0bb016dc/lxml-4.1.1-cp34-cp34m-win_amd64.whl#md5=c7f98ef43f35bbe129364c9427923ce1)

After downloading the wheel file,navigate your command prompt to the location where the .whl file is downloaded and then try 
**pip3 install "*downloaded whl file name*"**

Answer (score 0):

For windows, you can install lxml by exe file if also failed by whl. You can download it from [lxml](https://pypi.org/project/lxml/3.8.0/#files)

Hope this can help you.