# Installing libxml2 and libxslt in python 3.6

Tags: python-3.x, pip, lxml

I am having some problems installing lxml 3.6.4 in python 3.6 64bit using Pycharm and PIP.

```
pip install lxml==3.6.4

ERROR: b"'xslt-config' is not recognized as an internal or external command,\r\noperable program or batch file.\r\n"
** make sure the development packages of libxml2 and libxslt are installed **
```

When installing libxml

`pip install libxml2-dev`

I get the following error:

```
Collecting libxml2-dev
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement libxml2-dev (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for libxml2-dev
```

When running libxslt

`pip install libxslt`

I get this error

```
Collecting libxslt
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement libxslt (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for libxslt
```

The ultimate goal is to install pyiso on Pycharm.

My specs - Windows 7 - 64
Python 3.6

Comment: These are C libraries, not Python libraries. You may have more luck using e.g. Conda and installing libxml2.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to install lxml on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29440482/how-to-install-lxml-on-windows)

Comment: sudo apt-get install libxml2-dev libsxlt-dev

Comment: @pguardiario `apt-get` on Windows?

Comment: on wsl or apt-cyg on cygwin. I've gotten that bit working on both.

Answer (score 4):

**On Linux**, with the typo corrected, @pguardiario's comment above fixed this for me.

```
sudo apt-get install libxml2-dev libxslt-dev
```

Then:

```
conda install lxml
```

Or:

```
pip install lxml
```