# How to install lxml?

Tags: python, selenium, beautifulsoup, python-requests, scrapy

The following error appears when i try pip install lxml

```
C:\Program Files\Python311>pip install lxml
Collecting lxml
  Using cached lxml-4.9.1.tar.gz (3.4 MB)
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... done
Installing collected packages: lxml
  DEPRECATION: lxml is being installed using the legacy 'setup.py install' method, because it does not have a 'pyproject.toml' and the 'wheel' package is not installed. pip 23.1 will enforce this behaviour change. A possible replacement is to enable the '--use-pep517' option. Discussion can be found at https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/8559
  Running setup.py install for lxml ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × Running setup.py install for lxml did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [76 lines of output]
      Building lxml version 4.9.1.
      Building without Cython.
      Building against pre-built libxml2 andl libxslt libraries
      running install
      C:\Program Files\Python311\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\install.py:34: SetuptoolsDeprecationWarning: setup.py install is deprecated. Use build and pip and other standards-based tools.
        warnings.warn(
      running build
      running build_py
      creating build
      creating build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311
      creating build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\lxml
      copying src\lxml\builder.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\lxml
      copying src\lxml\cssselect.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\lxml
      copying src\lxml\doctestcompare.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\lxml
      copying src\lxml\ElementInclude.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\lxml
      copying src\lxml\pyclasslookup.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\lxml
      copying src\lxml\sax.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\lxml
      copying src\lxml\usedoctest.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\lxml
      copying src\lxml\_elementpath.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\lxml
      copying src\lxml\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\lxml
      creating build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\lxml\includes
      copying src\lxml\includes\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\lxml\includes
      creating build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\lxml\html
      copying src\lxml\html\builder.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\lxml\html
      copying src\lxml\html\clean.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\lxml\html
      copying src\lxml\html\defs.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\lxml\html
      copying src\lxml\html\diff.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\lxml\html
      copying src\lxml\html\ElementSoup.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\lxml\html
      copying src\lxml\html\formfill.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\lxml\html
      copying src\lxml\html\html5parser.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\lxml\html
      copying src\lxml\html\soupparser.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\lxml\html
      copying src\lxml\html\usedoctest.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\lxml\html
      copying src\lxml\html\_diffcommand.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\lxml\html
      copying src\lxml\html\_html5builder.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\lxml\html
      copying src\lxml\html\_setmixin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\lxml\html
      copying src\lxml\html\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\lxml\html
      creating build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\lxml\isoschematron
      copying src\lxml\isoschematron\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\lxml\isoschematron
      copying src\lxml\etree.h -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\lxml
      copying src\lxml\etree_api.h -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\lxml
      copying src\lxml\lxml.etree.h -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\lxml
      copying src\lxml\lxml.etree_api.h -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\lxml
      copying src\lxml\includes\c14n.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\lxml\includes
      copying src\lxml\includes\config.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\lxml\includes
      copying src\lxml\includes\dtdvalid.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\lxml\includes
      copying src\lxml\includes\etreepublic.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\lxml\includes
      copying src\lxml\includes\htmlparser.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\lxml\includes
      copying src\lxml\includes\relaxng.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\lxml\includes
      copying src\lxml\includes\schematron.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\lxml\includes
      copying src\lxml\includes\tree.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\lxml\includes
      copying src\lxml\includes\uri.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\lxml\includes
      copying src\lxml\includes\xinclude.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\lxml\includes
      copying src\lxml\includes\xmlerror.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\lxml\includes
      copying src\lxml\includes\xmlparser.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\lxml\includes
      copying src\lxml\includes\xmlschema.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\lxml\includes
      copying src\lxml\includes\xpath.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\lxml\includes
      copying src\lxml\includes\xslt.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\lxml\includes
      copying src\lxml\includes\__init__.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\lxml\includes
      copying src\lxml\includes\etree_defs.h -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\lxml\includes
      copying src\lxml\includes\lxml-version.h -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\lxml\includes
      creating build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\lxml\isoschematron\resources
      creating build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\lxml\isoschematron\resources\rng
      copying src\lxml\isoschematron\resources\rng\iso-schematron.rng -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\lxml\isoschematron\resources\rng
      creating build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\lxml\isoschematron\resources\xsl
      copying src\lxml\isoschematron\resources\xsl\RNG2Schtrn.xsl -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\lxml\isoschematron\resources\xsl
      copying src\lxml\isoschematron\resources\xsl\XSD2Schtrn.xsl -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\lxml\isoschematron\resources\xsl
      creating build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\lxml\isoschematron\resources\xsl\iso-schematron-xslt1
      copying src\lxml\isoschematron\resources\xsl\iso-schematron-xslt1\iso_abstract_expand.xsl -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\lxml\isoschematron\resources\xsl\iso-schematron-xslt1
      copying src\lxml\isoschematron\resources\xsl\iso-schematron-xslt1\iso_dsdl_include.xsl -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\lxml\isoschematron\resources\xsl\iso-schematron-xslt1
      copying src\lxml\isoschematron\resources\xsl\iso-schematron-xslt1\iso_schematron_message.xsl -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\lxml\isoschematron\resources\xsl\iso-schematron-xslt1
      copying src\lxml\isoschematron\resources\xsl\iso-schematron-xslt1\iso_schematron_skeleton_for_xslt1.xsl -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\lxml\isoschematron\resources\xsl\iso-schematron-xslt1
      copying src\lxml\isoschematron\resources\xsl\iso-schematron-xslt1\iso_svrl_for_xslt1.xsl -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\lxml\isoschematron\resources\xsl\iso-schematron-xslt1
      copying src\lxml\isoschematron\resources\xsl\iso-schematron-xslt1\readme.txt -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\lxml\isoschematron\resources\xsl\iso-schematron-xslt1
      running build_ext
      building 'lxml.etree' extension
      error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 or greater is required. Get it with "Microsoft C++ Build Tools": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/visual-cpp-build-tools/
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: legacy-install-failure

× Encountered error while trying to install package.
╰─> lxml

note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
hint: See above for output from the failure.
```

I try to run command : pip install lxml
and I expect to run this command without any specific error

Comment: Your error trace recommends this action: error: `Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 or greater is required. Get it with "Microsoft C++ Build Tools": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/visual-cpp-build-tools/` have you looked into this?

Comment: I don't know if it fits you, but I faced this same issue on Win10+Python3.11. When downgrading to Python3.8, I could install `lxml`. I don't need Python3.11 so it works so far for me ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you can download the lxml-3.4.2-cp34-none-win_amd64.whl and try to install  it, if you have something wrong try with the win_32 version:

Visit this link : [How to install lxml on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29440482/how-to-install-lxml-on-windows)

good luck