# Listing external wheel as platform specific dependency in pyproject.toml

Tags: pip, setuptools, python-packaging, pyproject.toml

I'm trying to list lxml as a dependency in my Python package. Specifically, another package requires it, but lxml is a pain in the ass to install on Windows, while it can be easily achieved in other platforms. The workaround I arrived at involves downloading a custom wheel file as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69507874/8225672) before configuring the rest, but I don't want this dependency to be checked on other platforms, as its Windows specific.

I've configured the dependencies section of my `pyproject.toml` as such:

```ini
dependencies = [
    'lxml @ https://download.lfd.uci.edu/pythonlibs/archived/lxml-4.9.0-cp311-cp311-win_amd64.whl#egg=lxml-4.9.0',
    'some-other-package',
]
```

and I'm able to build it with setuptools with no problems. However when I modify that line to include the Windows conditional:

```
'lxml @ https://download.lfd.uci.edu/pythonlibs/archived/lxml-4.9.0-cp311-cp311-win_amd64.whl#egg=lxml-4.9.0; sys_platform == "win32"',
```

it fails with the following error:

```py
DESCRIPTION:
    Project dependency specification according to PEP 508

GIVEN VALUE:
    "lxml @ https://download.lfd.uci.edu/pythonlibs/archived/lxml-4.9.0-cp311-cp311-win_amd64.whl#egg=lxml-4.9.0; sys_platform == \"win32\""

OFFENDING RULE: 'format'

DEFINITION:
    {
        "$id": "#/definitions/dependency",
        "title": "Dependency",
        "type": "string",
        "format": "pep508"
    }
...
ValueError: invalid pyproject.toml config: `project.dependencies[{data__dependencies_x}]`.
configuration error: `project.dependencies[{data__dependencies_x}]` must be pep508
```

Having read PEP 508 (and the accompanying [PEP 631](https://peps.python.org/pep-0631/#example)), the environment marker appears to be valid, so what am I doing wrong?

Comment: I think that the `#egg=lxml-4.9.0` part is not needed (it is not part of the specification). Have you tried without this part?

Comment: @sinoroc indeed I have. The "egg" is optional, but removing it doesn't seem to change much, I get the exact same error without it.

Comment: The error message kind of make it looks like it is a TOML formatting issue. But I can not see what this issue would be. Have you tried different quoting, different escaping? -- Or it could be a _setuptools_ bug.

Comment: I might have found the cause of your issue, thanks to [this similar bug report](https://github.com/pypa/setuptools/issues/1770). Maybe with an empty space on each side of the semicolon `;` this would work.

Comment: @sinoroc just minutes ago I arrived at a similar conclusion, from a different bug report. You're welcome to write that as answer and I will mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on a [similar *setuptools* bug report](https://github.com/pypa/setuptools/issues/1770), it seems like for a dependency specification to be [*PEP 508*](https://peps.python.org/pep-0508/)-conform in the case where it  contains a direct reference URL, there should be an empty space on each side of the semicolon `;`.

Also note, that as far as I know, the `#egg=lxml` part does not belong in a PEP 508 dependency specification.

So in your case, I guess it should be:
`lxml @ https://download.lfd.uci.edu/pythonlibs/archived/lxml-4.9.0-cp311-cp311-win_amd64.whl ; sys_platform == "win32"`.