# Libraries libxml2 and lxml doesn't install

Tags: python

The other day I decided to install an HTML parsing library called lxml. I installed it but got an error saying I didn't install Microsoft C++ Build Tools. I installed Build Tools and it fixed the problem with installing most of the libraries, but not with LXML. When I try to install the library I get this error:

```
×     Running setup.py install for lxml did not run successfully.
│     exit code: 1
╰─\> \[96 lines of output\]
Collecting lxml
Using cached lxml-4.9.1.tar.gz (3.4 MB)
Preparing metadata (setup.py) done
Installing collected packages: lxml
DEPRECATION: lxml is being installed using the legacy 'setup.py install' method, because it does not have a 'pyproject.toml' and the 'wheel' package is not installed. pip 23.1 will enforce this behaviour change. A possible replacement is to enable the '--use-pep517' option. Discussion can be found at https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/8559
Running setup.py install for lxml ... error
error: subprocess-exited-with-error
Building lxml version 4.9.1.
Building without Cython.
Building against pre-built libxml2 andl libxslt libraries
running install
C:\\Users\\Ivan\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python311\\Lib\\site-packages\\setuptools\\command\\install.py:34: SetuptoolsDeprecationWarning: setup.py install is deprecated. Use build and pip and other standards-based tools.
warnings.warn(
running build
running build_py
creating build
creating build\\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311
creating build\\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\\lxml
copying src\\lxml\\builder.py -\> build\\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\\lxml
copying src\\lxml\\cssselect.py -\> build\\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\\lxml
copying src\\lxml\\doctestcompare.py -\> build\\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\\lxml
copying src\\lxml\\ElementInclude.py -\> build\\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\\lxml
copying src\\lxml\\pyclasslookup.py -\> build\\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\\lxml
copying src\\lxml\\sax.py -\> build\\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\\lxml
copying src\\lxml\\usedoctest.py -\> build\\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\\lxml
copying src\\lxml_elementpath.py -\> build\\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\\lxml
copying src\\lxml\__init_\_.py -\> build\\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\\lxml
creating build\\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\\lxml\\includes
copying src\\lxml\\includes\__init_\_.py -\> build\\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\\lxml\\includes
creating build\\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\\lxml\\html
copying src\\lxml\\html\\builder.py -\> build\\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\\lxml\\html
copying src\\lxml\\html\\clean.py -\> build\\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\\lxml\\html
copying src\\lxml\\html\\defs.py -\> build\\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\\lxml\\html
copying src\\lxml\\html\\diff.py -\> build\\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\\lxml\\html
copying src\\lxml\\html\\ElementSoup.py -\> build\\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\\lxml\\html
copying src\\lxml\\html\\formfill.py -\> build\\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\\lxml\\html
copying src\\lxml\\html\\html5parser.py -\> build\\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\\lxml\\html
copying src\\lxml\\html\\soupparser.py -\> build\\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\\lxml\\html
copying src\\lxml\\html\\usedoctest.py -\> build\\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\\lxml\\html
copying src\\lxml\\html_diffcommand.py -\> build\\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\\lxml\\html
copying src\\lxml\\html_html5builder.py -\> build\\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\\lxml\\html
copying src\\lxml\\html_setmixin.py -\> build\\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\\lxml\\html
copying src\\lxml\\html\__init_\_.py -\> build\\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\\lxml\\html
creating build\\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\\lxml\\isoschematron
copying src\\lxml\\isoschematron\__init_\_.py -\> build\\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\\lxml\\isoschematron
copying src\\lxml\\etree.h -\> build\\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\\lxml
copying src\\lxml\\etree_api.h -\> build\\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\\lxml
copying src\\lxml\\lxml.etree.h -\> build\\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\\lxml
copying src\\lxml\\lxml.etree_api.h -\> build\\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\\lxml
copying src\\lxml\\includes\\c14n.pxd -\> build\\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\\lxml\\includes
copying src\\lxml\\includes\\config.pxd -\> build\\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\\lxml\\includes
copying src\\lxml\\includes\\dtdvalid.pxd -\> build\\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\\lxml\\includes
copying src\\lxml\\includes\\etreepublic.pxd -\> build\\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\\lxml\\includes
copying src\\lxml\\includes\\htmlparser.pxd -\> build\\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\\lxml\\includes
copying src\\lxml\\includes\\relaxng.pxd -\> build\\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\\lxml\\includes
copying src\\lxml\\includes\\schematron.pxd -\> build\\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\\lxml\\includes
copying src\\lxml\\includes\\tree.pxd -\> build\\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\\lxml\\includes
copying src\\lxml\\includes\\uri.pxd -\> build\\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\\lxml\\includes
copying src\\lxml\\includes\\xinclude.pxd -\> build\\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\\lxml\\includes
copying src\\lxml\\includes\\xmlerror.pxd -\> build\\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\\lxml\\includes
copying src\\lxml\\includes\\xmlparser.pxd -\> build\\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\\lxml\\includes
copying src\\lxml\\includes\\xmlschema.pxd -\> build\\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\\lxml\\includes
copying src\\lxml\\includes\\xpath.pxd -\> build\\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\\lxml\\includes
copying src\\lxml\\includes\\xslt.pxd -\> build\\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\\lxml\\includes
copying src\\lxml\\includes\__init_\_.pxd -\> build\\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\\lxml\\includes
copying src\\lxml\\includes\\etree_defs.h -\> build\\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\\lxml\\includes
copying src\\lxml\\includes\\lxml-version.h -\> build\\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\\lxml\\includes
creating build\\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\\lxml\\isoschematron\\resources
creating build\\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\\lxml\\isoschematron\\resources\\rng
copying src\\lxml\\isoschematron\\resources\\rng\\iso-schematron.rng -\> build\\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\\lxml\\isoschematron\\resources\\rng
creating build\\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\\lxml\\isoschematron\\resources\\xsl
copying src\\lxml\\isoschematron\\resources\\xsl\\RNG2Schtrn.xsl -\> build\\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\\lxml\\isoschematron\\resources\\xsl
copying src\\lxml\\isoschematron\\resources\\xsl\\XSD2Schtrn.xsl -\> build\\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\\lxml\\isoschematron\\resources\\xsl
creating build\\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\\lxml\\isoschematron\\resources\\xsl\\iso-schematron-xslt1
copying src\\lxml\\isoschematron\\resources\\xsl\\iso-schematron-xslt1\\iso_abstract_expand.xsl -\> build\\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\\lxml\\isoschematron\\resources\\xsl\\iso-schematron-xslt1
copying src\\lxml\\isoschematron\\resources\\xsl\\iso-schematron-xslt1\\iso_dsdl_include.xsl -\> build\\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\\lxml\\isoschematron\\resources\\xsl\\iso-schematron-xslt1
copying src\\lxml\\isoschematron\\resources\\xsl\\iso-schematron-xslt1\\iso_schematron_message.xsl -\> build\\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\\lxml\\isoschematron\\resources\\xsl\\iso-schematron-xslt1
copying src\\lxml\\isoschematron\\resources\\xsl\\iso-schematron-xslt1\\iso_schematron_skeleton_for_xslt1.xsl -\> build\\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\\lxml\\isoschematron\\resources\\xsl\\iso-schematron-xslt1
copying src\\lxml\\isoschematron\\resources\\xsl\\iso-schematron-xslt1\\iso_svrl_for_xslt1.xsl -\> build\\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\\lxml\\isoschematron\\resources\\xsl\\iso-schematron-xslt1
copying src\\lxml\\isoschematron\\resources\\xsl\\iso-schematron-xslt1\\readme.txt -\> build\\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\\lxml\\isoschematron\\resources\\xsl\\iso-schematron-xslt1
running build_ext
building 'lxml.etree' extension
creating build\\temp.win-amd64-cpython-311
creating build\\temp.win-amd64-cpython-311\\Release
creating build\\temp.win-amd64-cpython-311\\Release\\src
creating build\\temp.win-amd64-cpython-311\\Release\\src\\lxml
"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2022\\BuildTools\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.34.31933\\bin\\HostX86\\x64\\cl.exe" /c /nologo /O2 /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -DCYTHON_CLINE_IN_TRACEBACK=0 -Isrc -Isrc\\lxml\\includes -IC:\\Users\\Ivan\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python311\\include -IC:\\Users\\Ivan\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python311\\Include "-IC:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2022\\BuildTools\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.34.31933\\include" "-IC:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2022\\BuildTools\\VC\\Auxiliary\\VS\\include" "-IC:\\Program Files (x86)\\Windows Kits\\10\\include\\10.0.22000.0\\ucrt" "-IC:\\Program Files (x86)\\Windows Kits\\10\\include\\10.0.22000.0\\um" "-IC:\\Program Files (x86)\\Windows Kits\\10\\include\\10.0.22000.0\\shared" "-IC:\\Program Files (x86)\\Windows Kits\\10\\include\\10.0.22000.0\\winrt" "-IC:\\Program Files (x86)\\Windows Kits\\10\\include\\10.0.22000.0\\cppwinrt" /Tcsrc\\lxml\\etree.c /Fobuild\\temp.win-amd64-cpython-311\\Release\\src\\lxml\\etree.obj -w
cl: Є®¬ ­¤­ п бва®Є  warning D9025: ЇҐаҐ®ЇаҐ¤Ґ«Ґ­ЁҐ "/W3" ­  "/w"
etree.c
C:\\Users\\Ivan\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-4d5gevsf\\lxml_f080c12d757741aebf47ba5d7a933c12\\src\\lxml\\includes/etree_defs.h(14): fatal error C1083: ЌҐ г¤ Ґвбп ®вЄалвм д ©« ўЄ«озҐ­ЁҐ: libxml/xmlversion.h: No such file or directory,
Compile failed: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2022\\BuildTools\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.34.31933\\bin\\HostX86\\x64\\cl.exe' failed with exit code 2
creating Users
creating Users\\Ivan
creating Users\\Ivan\\AppData
creating Users\\Ivan\\AppData\\Local
creating Users\\Ivan\\AppData\\Local\\Temp
"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2022\\BuildTools\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.34.31933\\bin\\HostX86\\x64\\cl.exe" /c /nologo /O2 /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -I/usr/include/libxml2 "-IC:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2022\\BuildTools\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.34.31933\\include" "-IC:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2022\\BuildTools\\VC\\Auxiliary\\VS\\include" "-IC:\\Program Files (x86)\\Windows Kits\\10\\include\\10.0.22000.0\\ucrt" "-IC:\\Program Files (x86)\\Windows Kits\\10\\include\\10.0.22000.0\\um" "-IC:\\Program Files (x86)\\Windows Kits\\10\\include\\10.0.22000.0\\shared" "-IC:\\Program Files (x86)\\Windows Kits\\10\\include\\10.0.22000.0\\winrt" "-IC:\\Program Files (x86)\\Windows Kits\\10\\include\\10.0.22000.0\\cppwinrt" /TcC:\\Users\\Ivan\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\xmlXPathInitei2tmnxs.c /FoUsers\\Ivan\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\xmlXPathInitei2tmnxs.obj
xmlXPathInitei2tmnxs.c
C:\\Users\\Ivan\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\xmlXPathInitei2tmnxs.c(1): fatal error C1083: ЌҐ г¤ Ґвбп ®вЄалвм д ©« ўЄ«озҐ­ЁҐ: libxml/xpath.h: No such file or directory,
error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2022\\BuildTools\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.34.31933\\bin\\HostX86\\x64\\cl.exe' failed with exit code 2
\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*
Could not find function xmlCheckVersion in library libxml2. Is libxml2 installed?
\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*
\[end of output\]
× Encountered error while trying to install package.
╰─\> lxml

note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: legacy-install-failure

× Encountered error while trying to install package.
╰─\> lxml

note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
hint: See above for output from the failure.
```

I tried to install the libxml2 library, but I get an error if I try to install the library using the command:

```
pip install --user libxml2-python
```

And also an error when installing the library using the command:

```
pip install --user libxml2-python3
```

```
The error itself:
Collecting libxml2-python3
  Using cached libxml2-python3-2.9.5.tar.gz (216 kB)
  Preparing metadata (setup.py): started
  Preparing metadata (setup.py): finished with status 'error'

  error: subprocess-exited-with-error
  
  python setup.py egg_info did not run successfully.
  exit code: 1
  
  [1 lines of output]
  failed to find headers for libxml2: update includes_dir
  [end of output]
  
  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: metadata-generation-failed

Encountered error while generating package metadata.

See above for output.

note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
hint: See above for details.
```

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31894186/5320906) may help you.

Comment: if am i have python 3.11?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and I did the next:

1. pip install lxml - didn't work for me - I had to download here ([https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#lxml](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/%7Egohlke/pythonlibs/#lxml)) the xlml from the version python I have in my machine (lxml-4.9.0-cp311-cp311-win_amd64.whl - I have python 3.11-64-bit)
2. I installed the file - (pip install C:\Users\daler\Downloads\lxml-4.9.0-cp311-cp311-win_amd64.whl) type the path were the lxml you downloaded.
3. Then of that, I could install the libraries I needed in my case (pip install yfinance) finally was installed cause I had the same problem than you.